# Gebräuchlichkeit von Wörtern mit und ohne "-s" am Ende (Beispiel: "nochmal / nochmals")

Tags: usage, dialect, adverb, standard-german

Es gibt einige Wörter im Deutschen, die am Wortende gegebenenfalls mit einem *-s* geschrieben werden können, wo es aber auch durchaus weggelassen werden kann. Historisch gibt es viele Wörter, die einst ohne *-s* verwendet wurden, wovon die meisten aber "ausgestorben" sind.

Es gibt aber noch eine Handvoll Wörter, wo heutzutage beide Varianten regelmäßig verwendet werden. In aller Regel ist eines der Wörter im Gebrauch "landschaftlich", wie es der Duden nennt, was aber nicht zwingend so ist. Dazu gehören die Wörter *nochmal/nochmals*, *weiter/weiters* und *öfter/öfters*.

Ersteres fällt in gewisser Hinsicht in eine besondere Gruppe, da es viele Wörter mit *-mal* bzw. *-mals* gibt. Aus dieser Gruppe ist es zumindest das Wort, das die meisten Verwendungen beider Varianten hat.

Q1: Bezüglich der drei genannten Beispiele: Es wird aus Duden und Co. nicht klar, wo genau der Gebrauch mit oder ohne *-s* ist. Kann man hier eine einheitliche Nord-Süd-Trennung ziehen und behaupten, dass im einen Teil Deutschlands **ausschließlich** die Variante mit *-s* verwendet wird (also für jedes dieser Wörter), während auf der anderen Seite der imaginären Grenze grundsätzlich kein *-s* angehängt wird. Oder sind es nur vereinzelte Regionen, verstreut in Deutschland, wo man zur einen oder halt anderen Variante greift.
Und wie sieht es mit der Schweiz und Österreich aus?
Kann man überhaupt davon ausgehen, dass jemand, der an beispielsweise *nochmals* das *-s* anhängt, dies auch für alle anderen Wörter so handhabt, sprich *weiters*, *öfters* etc.

Q2: Bezüglich Wörter, die auf *-mal* bzw. *mals* enden: Kann man davon ausgehen, dass eine allgemeine Verschiebung von "ohne *-s*" hin zu "mit *-s*" besteht? Wie gesagt: Es scheint so, dass es viele dieser Wörter mal ohne *-s* gegeben hat (z. B. niemal, oftmal), und bei den Wörtern *zumals*, *diesmals*, *manchmals* und *wiedermals*, welche eigentlich noch eindeutig ohne *-s* verwendet werden, findet man dennoch bei einer Google-Suche eine recht hohe Trefferquote.
Oder ist es so, dass bei den Wörtern, wo es früher einmal (oder vielleicht doch *einmals*?) auch die Variante ohne *-s* gab, schon immer beide Varianten möglich waren und sich dann einfach das *-s* durchgesetzt hat und demzufolge keine Verschiebung zum *-s* hin stattfindet.

Frage am Rande (bitte Kommentare benutzen): Gibt es noch weitere Beispiele, die mir entgangen sind? Insbesondere solche, die nicht auf *-mal* bzw. *-mals* enden.

Zum Abschluss alle Wörter, die ich gefunden habe, auf die die Frage zutrifft:

Mit Duden-Einträgen für beiden Formen:

- *weiter* <sub>(in der Bedeutung *weiterhin*)</sub> / *weiters*
- *öfter* / *öfters* <sub>(Fälschlicherweise auch oft als Komparativ von *oft*.)</sub>
- *nochmal* (*noch mal*) / *nochmals*
- *vielmal* / *vielmals*

Nur Duden-Einträge für die Variante ohne *-s*, aber hoher Hitquote auf Google mit *-s*:

- *einmal* <sub>(In der Bedeutung *mal*)</sub> / *einmals*
- *zumal* / *zumals*
- *diesmal* / *diesmals*
- *manchmal* / *manchmals*
- *wiedermal* / *wiedermals*

Das Grimm'sche Wörterbuch beinhaltet zu den folgenden Wörtern auch noch Einträge ohne *-s*, auch wenn hier die Verwendung wohl eindeutig veraltet ist:
*damals*, *jemals*, *ehemals*, *niemals*, *oftmals*, *vormals*, *mehrmals*, *nachmals*, *hernachmals*

---

Es gibt einige wenige Wörter, die in einigen Regionen in der Umgangssprache mit der Endung *-st* verwendet werden. Es gibt auch einige Google-Treffer dazu, aber durch kein Dictionary belegt.

- *neulich* / *neulichst*
- *kürzlich* / *kürzlichst*

---

Die folgenden Wortpaare bedeuten etwas Unterschiedliches:

- *Erstmal* / *erstmals*
- *bereit* / *bereits*

---

Interessanterweise war mir das Wort *einmal* entgangen, obwohl ich es sogar einmal im Fließtext verwendet habe. Für *einmals* gibt es zwar eine überraschend hohe Trefferquote auf Google, die Kurzform *mals* ergibt aber nahezu 0 relevante Treffer. Zumindest ist es schwer, was Brauchbares zu finden.

Comment: Weiteres Beispiel: minimal / minimalst

Comment: Weiteres Beispiel: am ehesten / ehestens (!= frühestens) – baldig / baldigst

Comment: Weiteres Beispiel: extrem / extremst

Comment: Weiteres Beispiel: nirgend / nirgends

Comment: Weiteres Beispiel: gänzlich / gänzlichst

Comment: Duden ist eigentlich kein Lexikon für Deutsch als Fremdsprache. Sei also nicht enttäuscht, wenn Duden auf viele deiner Fragen nicht eingeht. Ich glaube, hier hat Deutschland noch viel nachzuholen. Oder gibt es so was wie das englische Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary für Deutsch?

Comment: Im Grimm unter "Mal" eine Auflistung vieler Varianten, die heute teils unüblich sind, teils weiterhin üblich: vgl. dazu die zusammenrückungen abermals (neben abermal), damals (neben damal und damalen), desmals (unter damals th. 2, 701), diesmals (neben diesmal und diesmalen), dortmals, einsmals, einstmals, erstmals, ehmals, jemals, jetztmals (neben jetztmal), mehrmals, nachmals, niemals, nochmals, oftmals, vormals;

Answer (score 9):

**Q1:** Ja es gibt so eine Grenze: In Österreich werden häufig Wörter mit -s am Ende verwendet, was in Deutschland als ungrammatikalisch gelten würde. Zum Beispiel heißt es in Österreich "weiters", in Deutschland aber "weiterhin", wobei das eine andere Bedeutung hat als "weiter". Ähnliche Unterschiede gibt es auch bei -s- als Fugenlaut. In Deutschland sagt man "Zugführer", in Österreich "Zugsführer". Eine generelle Regel ist mir aber nicht bekannt.

**Q2:** Obwohl es viele Google-Treffer zu den Wörtern mit -s gibt, gibt es diese Wörter nicht. Also

> zumals, diesmals, manchmals, wiedermals

gibt es alle nicht. Ich habe diese Wörter auch noch nie gehört und wenn jemand sie benutzt, würde er mir eher ungebildet erscheinen. Bei den Wörtern, die auf -mals enden, wird dadurch ein Plural eingedrückt. Zum Beispiel

> Ich danke Ihnen vielmals. = Ich danke Ihnen viele Male.

Dementsprechend gibt es -mals auch nur bei Wörtern, bei denen eine Pluralbedeutung Sinn ergibt. Zum Beispiel dein Beispiel "manchmals" gibt es nicht.

Einige der Formen, die du genannt hast, sind außerdem eher veraltet. Zum Beispiel sagt niemand mehr "vielmal", sondern "vielmals". Oder als Adjektiv "vielmalig".

Ich hoffe, meine Antwort hilft dir etwas.

Answer (score 1):

Man findet was über solche Doppelformen im Band 9 der Duden-Reihe: Richtiges und gutes Deutsch (Zweifelsfälle).

Zu **öfter/öfters** sagt Duden:
Von den beiden Adverbformen wird heute **öfter** bevorzugt. Die Form **öfters** kommt häufig in der Umgangssprache vor. In Österreich ist sie allgemein üblich.

Ehrlich gesagt, ich mußte das nachschauen und hätte spontan gesagt, das sind zwei gleichbedeutende Varianten.