# What form is “öfters” that it requires an “s” (sentence shared in post)

Tags: declension, comparative

In this sentence, why does “öfters” have the “s”? I believe the verb is in Konjunktive II, but why is the word “**öfter**” being modified?

“Wenn ich mehr Zeit hätte, ginge ich **öfters** spazieren.”

Comment: It's basically synonym to "häufiger": https://www.dwds.de/wb/%C3%B6fters

Comment: The question [Gebräuchlichkeit von Wörtern mit und ohne "-s" am Ende (Beispiel: "nochmal / nochmals")](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/5795/41282) also mentions "öfters".

Answer (score 4):

In your example you can choose *öfter* or *öfters* as you please.

There is the difference, that *öfter* is a comparative as you correctly observed. So in most cases it asks for something else to be compared to, as opposed to *öfters* which can happily appear without comparison (meaning *somwhat frequently*). Since your sentence has the comparison situation (you **don't** have more time) both are correct.

Note, that comparatives can appear on their own with a different meaning. [This question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/11884/1696) concerns that construction, called *absolute comparative*.

Answer (score 3):

I fully agree with the existing [answer (guidot)](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73412/) on the **semantics** of *öfters* vs. *öfter*: *öfter* can be used in comparisons ("öfter als..."), or as a standalone adverb ("somewhat frequently"); *öfters* only has the second usage.

I would like to add something specifically on the **ending -s**, since this is actually the core of your question: "Why is *öfter* being modified?". This is originally **a genitive ending**.

[David Vogt](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73414/) suggests that the *-s* is simply the "**adverbial suffix** that occurs in many other words as well: *anders, stets, links, besonders, eigens*". That is, a suffix that creates an adverb from a word that can *only* be used as an adjective (*ander-*, ... *eigen-*).

However, this doesn't apply to *öfters*, since *öfter* is already an adverb that can cover the same semantic ground. Therefore, I disagree with reading the *-s* as an adverbial suffix.

Instead, it has its roots in the **genitive** declension, which is commonly marked by *-s*. I quote (and adapt) from [the DWB](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/%C3%B6fters):

> **öfters**, Adv. Seit dem 17. Jahrh. wird der Genitiv des Komparativs *öfter* als Adv. gebraucht neben und statt *öfter* [...]; durch Ellipse entstanden aus *öfters Mals* (s. DWb *oftermals* bei *oftmal* 2, b).

In other words, *öfters* was the **genitive** of [a comparative adjective] *öfter*, commonly used in the expression *öfters **Mals***, i.e. "on rather frequent occasion". (A more modern option: *öfter mal*.)

The existence of the synonymous expression *des Öfteren* also underpins this explanation of *öfters*. By surface analysis, *des Öfteren* is clearly a **genitive** form of the nominalized adjective *öfter*. I believe that *des Weiteren* and *weiters* display the same pattern.

Finally, note that there still is a usage of *öfter-* as an **(attributive) adjective**, besides its chief function as adverb (*seine öfteren Besuche*, *bei öfterer Verwendung*...), which [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/oefter) characterizes as "umgangssprachlich".

Comment: Your analysis sounds very convincing to me -- When reading David's answer, I also had the idea that _öfters_ means _öfter mals_. But he provided some sources where it is actually used as comparative. I guess, originally, _öfters_ was a genitive, but is now used in both ways, at least by a relevant amount of speakers. I think, a short paragraph taking this evidence into account would further improve your already very good and interesting post.

Comment: Die Belege bei DWB betreffen ausschließlich "oftermals" und die Behauptung, dass "ofters mals" dem gleichstehe, kann insoweit nicht mehr als eine unbewiesene Behauptung sein. Wenn man solche Behauptung aufrecht erhalten will, bedürfte es einer tiefergehenden Behandlung dieses scheinbaren genitiv Adverbs. Obwohl Adverben offenkundig gar nicht gebeugt werden, ist eine Abhandlung darüber aus einschlägigen Quellen aber nicht zu erwarten.

Comment: Siehe Außerdem Adelung, "Wie öfters, für wie oft, ist im Hochdeutschen ungangbar." Ansonsten noch reichlich belegt in Goethe's Sprache (Goethe Wörterbuch: *öfters*, woerterbuchnetz.de), wobei zumindest einmal wegen Kontrast mit "manchmal" die entsprechende Wendung durchscheint, vgl. *manches mal*, *einstmals* usw, wobei wegen engl. *some* neben *so manches so mancher* und engl. *so many* wiederum Zweifel an der Herleitung (vgl. *Menge*) nicht unbegründet wären.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, *öfter* and *öfters* are synonyms. They can be used to express a comparison (although many speakers seem to prefer *öfter* for this use).

> Passiert das jetzt öfters als früher? (*Tagesspiegel*, 31.3.2001)*
> *Does this happen more frequently now than before?*

They can also be used to express a certain frequency of something (*absoluter Komparativ* in German; compare English *an older gentleman*): *öfter, öfters* "from time to time, every now and then, on occasion; repeatedly, frequently, many times".

> Das ist eine Erfahrung, die ich schon öfters gemacht hatte.
> *That's an experience I've had many times before.*

The *-s* is an adverbial suffix that occurs in many other words as well: *anders, stets, links, besonders, eigens*.

* <sup>Some further examples from newspapers found by searching for *öfters als* in [DWDS corpora](https://www.dwds.de/d/korpora/public):</sup>

> <sup>Entsprechend komme es öfters als früher vor, dass Betroffene fest vereinbarte Termine versäumten […]
>
> Man denkt viel öfters als sonst vor einem Spiel an mögliche Situationen […]
>
> Auf Fotos sah man ihn nun öfters als früher entspannt lächeln […]
>
> Leider verfehlt er den Korb aber auch öfters als früher bei den Chicago Bulls.
>
> Am Mittwochabend und am Donnerstagvormittag klingelte beim Trainer von Hertha BSC das Handy noch öfters als gewöhnlich.
>
> Der Gläubige muß öfters als bisher wiederkommen und das Lichtlein entzünden.
>
> Auch die Berufstätigen gönnen sich öfters als andere eine Ferientour.
>
> Mehrmals wurden sie vorübergehend festgenommen – sie öfters als er.
>
> Und öfters als man glaubt ist es ein dunkler Winkel in einem Keller der Peripherie, wo das junge Glück beginnt, wo eine Familie begründet wird.</sup>